# How do you do a left and mid in Python without any Python libraries?

Tags: python

FYI I am new to Python and this website!

I have a csv file:

```
Product Number,Account Number,Transactions,Year Number,Left Output,Mid Output
43854835,12345,23123,12,12,45
4353454,23456,123213213,4,23,56
7657657,34567,321321,5,34,67
21321312,45678,321321,8,45,78
21312313,56789,2131233,3,56,89
```

If I want to refer to column 2 as the one where I need to conduct left and mid in Python, what is the best approach without libraries? I also want to append at the last column of the data as seen in the image.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with automation. Please do not randomly add tags to your post. Tags have meaning and relevance here, so it's important to use them as intended. Read the tag description before adding it to your post. In this case, the appropriate tag would have been for the version of Python you're using. Plelase [edit] to add it. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: You could easily put the contents of that image in a simple text-based table. Please do so.

Comment: What is a "left and mid function"? Those aren't terms I'm remotely familiar with in Python, so presumably they're from some other context that you have not explained.

Comment: @Blckknght It's for an excel spreadsheet; they are trying to replicate the `=LEFT(text, size)` and `=MID(text, start, size)` macros from excel in Python, to be run on a dataset that is too large too open.

Answer (score 0):

This takes in a `.csv` file, reads the lines into a list, appends new data using the `LEFT` and `MID` functions and saves it to a new file (`newFile.csv`). This works according to the data in the imgur link.

**Note**: the script is hardly optimised; it was tested on ~2 million lines and it took a couple of minutes and ALOT of ram (2-3GB), so be careful about running this (backup original csv file, save work, close programs, etc ...)

I could modify this to batch process lines so memory is freed as well as maybe some sort of cache, but since I'm assuming it will be used sparingly, it should probably be fine.

```
filename = "myFile.csv"
# don't want to overwrite original
new_filename = "newFile.csv"

def LEFT(s, length):
    # example: LEFT("apple",3) returns "app".
    return str(s[:length])

def MID(s, start, length):
    # example: MID("apple",2,3) returns "ppl"
    return str(s[start - 1: start - 1 + length])

# read file contents into list
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    # store file data in a list
    file_data = file.read().splitlines()

# loop and append new data to list
for i, line in enumerate(file_data):
    # ignore header
    if (i == 0): continue;
    # parse 2nd column
    second_column = line.split(",")[1]
    # append 5th and 6th column
    file_data[i] += "," + LEFT(second_column, 2)   \
                  + "," + MID(second_column, 4, 2)

# write modified list to new file
with open(new_filename, 'w') as file:
    for line in file_data:
        file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i define that i want column 6 to be used only when focusing on doing the mid and left functions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you please edit the question with an example that shows the expected output and I can take a look...

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be done in Python? If all you need is to run `=LEFT` a bunch of times, type `=LEFT(B2,2)` in `E2`, and drag from the bottom corner down to `E6` to run the command for all values (you can do the same for mid with `=MID(B2, 4, 2)`.

Comment: The reason to do it in python is because this is a large data set that I can't open in excel so it is easier if I do the left and mid in python and then split the excel files so they can be opened. The image is just an example of the large data set. Thanks!

Comment: Does your csv file looks like this `43854835 ... ... ... ... 12345 23123 12 12 45`

Comment: And so you want the 6th column to be used to return the last two for left and mid?

Comment: So if you follow the example image, i want to use the 2nd column to find the left and mid and i want the output to be in the 5th and 6th column of the csv file.

Comment: Okay, I'll write something that will parse like this then `43854835,12345,23123,12,12,45`. How do you plan on splitting the file?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help! I have a python script that splits the large file by a million rows per csv file.

Comment: Let me know how this goes. Cheers.